# Is there way to programmatically check (or otherwise) 'Send as SMS' option is enabled or not?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to build an app (ios, swift), that needs to check if 'Settings -> Messages - > 'Send as SMS' option is enabled or not. Based on that, App will perform some action (some image display). How can I check programmatically whether 'Send as SMS' is enabled or not?

This is for a new ios app (ios 11+, swift4+). I tried to look for APIs to access 'ios Settings', there seem to be none.

I expect some existance of some API/classes that can be used to access the status of 'Settings->Messages->Send as SMS'

Comment: There is no api for this setting.